# How to Create Registry key using a batfile

Tags: windows, registry, batch-file

> Need to Create a Registry Key using bat file.Can I create Reg Key using Command prompt or a bat file.

The main purpose behind this ,  I want to create envoirment variable using bat file.

Comment: Wouldn't this rather belong on serverfault.com? Anyway, I would check out Powershell (or run a vbs script).

Comment: Because registry manipulation from a batch file can be painful. However, many people do not realize that blindly suggesting PowerShell/VBS/Cygwin/Gnuwin32/whatever is not always an answer. Still, in your case I wouldn't even touch the registry directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Windows built-in command line tools, either `regedit.exe` or `reg.exe`, see:

- [Regedit](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php)
- [REG Command in Windows XP](http://www.petri.co.il/reg_command_in_windows_xp.htm)
- [Reading NT's Registry with REG.EXE](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregistry.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yes u can create Registry Key using Batch file

here is an example:

for disabling task manager using .bat file:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /f /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

for enabling task manager:

```
reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v DisableTaskMgr /f
```

You can take Help by entering reg/? in command prompt for various options.

Enjoy.........

Answer (score 0):

SET variable=string

Comment: Environment variables (what you're setting in your example) are different from registry keys.

Comment: But his main purpose is to set environment variables

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a persistent environment variable (i.e. one that not only applies to the current session) you can use `setx`. No need to mess around with the registry directly if there is a program to do it for you:

```
SetX has three ways of working:

Syntax 1:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var value [/M]

Syntax 2:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var /K regpath [/M]

Syntax 3:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]]
         /F file {var {/A x,y | /R x,y string}[/M] | /X} [/D delimiters]

Description:
    Creates or modifies environment variables in the user or system
    environment. Can set variables based on arguments, regkeys or
    file input.
```

Comment: It seems SETX is specific to Windows 7

Comment: It's been in core Windows since at least Vista. Having never used XP I have no idea as how that is on legacy systems. It was part of a Resource kit previously. Furthermore, you never said anything about an OS restriction, so I assumed something recent.